# How to find Last records of ID with Group by and check with time?

Tags: mysql

This is my main table which contain this type of records

```
id  | a_id | datetime
------------------------
1   |   1  | 2016-01-07 15:42:14
2   |   1  | 2016-01-08 16:42:14
3   |   1  | 2016-01-09 17:42:14
4   |   2  | 2016-01-07 15:42:14
5   |   2  | 2016-01-08 16:42:14
6   |   2  | 2016-01-09 17:42:14
7   |   2  | 2016-01-10 18:42:14
8   |   2  | 2016-01-11 19:42:14
```

and I want output like :

Assume my current time is 17:50:00, So my below result inserted before half hour of my current time.

```
id  | a_id | amount
------------------------
3   |   1  | 2016-01-09 17:42:14
```

How can I get this kind of output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like should work
if max(a_id) dosent work then you should also put there datetime field name but first convert that in string using sql

```
SELECT p1.* , p1.a_id as a_id
            FROM tbl_name p1
            INNER JOIN
            (
                SELECT max(a_id) as MaxVal
                FROM tbl_name
                GROUP BY a_id
            ) p2
              ON p1.id = p2.id
              AND p1.a_id = p2.MaxVal
            WHERE p1.datetime >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 0.5 HOUR)
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105006/discussion-between-sagar-patel-and-jay-doshi).

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE `date_time` 
BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -30 MINUTE) AND NOW();
```

Comment: And how is your answer different from Giorgos Betsos?

Comment: i add it same time but this is same as Giorgos i dont know before

Comment: Got it. Just wanted to know. It happens most of the time :)

Comment: @RahulTripathi ok but i am 1 min late from giogos so every body can blame me you copied from other person's post

Comment: As I said, it happens that you can miss to answer at first. And if you are afraid that people might *blame* you then you can delete it as it is mostly the same as Giorgos. Also as per the OP's comment, it is not solving his/her issue :P

Comment: I want group by because I want last record of a_id and then I want to check that is it between current time and before half an hour.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE `datetime` BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -30 MINUTE) AND NOW()
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7d0b5/3)

**Edit:**

To get the latest-per-group records and *then* find whether these records fall within a specified interval, you can use the following query:

```
SELECT id, a_id, `datetime`
FROM (
  SELECT id, a_id, `datetime`,
         @rn := IF(@aid = a_id, @rn + 1,
                   IF(@aid := a_id, 1, 1)) AS rn
  FROM mytable
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0, @aid := 0) AS vars
  ORDER BY a_id, `datetime` DESC) AS t
WHERE t.rn = 1 AND 
      `datetime` BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -30 MINUTE) AND NOW()
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7d0b5/13)

Comment: How can I do with GROUP BY query?

Comment: @JayDoshi Why would you need a `GROUP BY`?

Comment: @JayDoshi:- You dont need to use Group By in this case.

Comment: I want group by because I want last record of a_id and then I want to check that is it between current time and before half an hour.

Comment: @JayDoshi What do you mean by *last record of a_id*?

Comment: It means id=3(where a_id=1) and id=8 (where a_id=2). and then check with these record that is it between current time to before half an hour.

Comment: @JayDoshi OK, got it. Check the edit I made. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone's over-thinking this...

```
SELECT *
  FROM main 
 WHERE datetime < NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE 
 ORDER
   BY datetime DESC 
  LIMIT 1;
```